# Valuations and places - decomposition and inertia group

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

I feel very uncomfortable with some aspects of the theory of valuations, places, and valuation rings. Here is one of my problems : Assume that L/K is a finite Galois extension of fields, and that F is a place from K to its residual field k, whose associated valuation ring is discrete.
F extends to a place F' of L, from L to a finite algebraic extension k' of k, which we suppose to be the residual field of F'.
According to the litterature (Bourbaki, "commutative algebra", chap VI, Fried and Jarden, "Field arithmetic"), if e(F'/F) is the ramification index of F' over K, f(F'/F) is the residual degree of F' over K, and g is the number of non equivalent places extending F to L, there holds [L:K] = e f g.
Also, if D is the decomposition group of F' over K and J is its inertia group over K, then e(F'/F) = |J| and |D| = e(F'/F)f(F'/F).
Everything seems to be nice. Well, let see : I agree with everything as long as k'/k is separable, which is always the case if K is a number field (since then k is a finite field). But suppose that k'/k is not separable.
The decomposition group D of F' over F is the set of all automorphisms s of Gal(L/K) that leaves the valuation ring associated to F' globally invariant: this means that F's is equivalent to F' for all s in D (two places A and B are equivalent if there exists an automorphism s' of k'/k such that B = s'A, hence the place As is equivalent to A by the definition of the decomposition group). Since the natural homomorphism from D to Aut(k'/k) is surjective (Frobenius theorem), it is clear that Aut(k'/k) is isomorphic to D/J (J is the kernel of the said epimorphism). So, |D|/|J| = |Aut(k'/k)|, and there holds |D| = |J|.|Aut(k'/k)| = |J|.$[k':k]_{sep}$. Consequently, |D| is different from e(F'/F)f(F'/F) since f(F'/F) = [k':k] and e(F'/F) = |J|, in contradiction with the literature.
Everything would have been OK if f(F'/F) had been defined to be equal to $[k':k]_{sep}$, but then the formula [L:K] = e f g would not hold anymore.
I would appreciate some help to solve this paradox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your understanding is good, maybe the terminology needs a little clarification:

|k':k| = |k'<sub>sep</sub>:k||k'<sub>pi</sub>:k| 
i.e. f = f<sub>sep</sub>f<sub>pi</sub>

|D/J| = f<sub>sep</sub>

|L:K| = efg

example:  K=F(T)((X)), L=F(T<sup>1/p</sup>)((X)), valuation=X-adic, k=F(T), k'=F(T<sup>1/p</sup>), e=1, f=p, f<sub>sep</sub>=1, g=1

Comment: thx. So, what was false is |D| = ef (despite this is what Fried and Jarden wrote). My question is : the terminology $f_{sep}$ and $f_{pi}$ is yours or is it something usual ? if it is the case, can you point to some reference for me ? thx

Comment: @MikeTeX : The notations were made by me for this post.  The complete local case (such as the example above) has the essence of your residue field extension situation.  Serre's "Local Fields" is a good reference on DVRs though I think it mainly covers separable residue field extensions.

Comment: Here's a nice example with L/K separable degree p and k'/k purely inseparable: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57838/an-integral-ring-extension-that-b-m-is-not-separable-over-a-m

Comment: @MikeTeX : Here's a reference: Serre, "Local Fields", p. 21

Comment: In the nice example cited above with y^p+xy-t over k(t)[[x]], y has an "algebraic x-adic expansion" y=t^(1/p) - t^(1/p^2)x^(1/p) + t^(1/p^3)x^((p+1)/p^2)) ... whose exponents accumulate although y is unramified.

Comment: Unfortunately, the examples you gave does not help me solving the paradox, unless I missed something. In the example above L/K is not Galois. Similarly, the examples in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57838/an-integral-ring-extension-that-b-m-is-not-separable-over-a-m, the first one does not provide an extension of valued field (at a first glance), and in the second one L/K is not Galois again. What may help me would be an example of a finite Galois extension of discrete valued field (L,w)/(K,v) such that the corresponding extension of residual fields is inseparable.

Comment: David Lampert : thx again for the sources. Unfortunately, the book of Serre is on loan in my library, so I can't check what is written here. But according to the citations, I think , as you said, that it it mainly covers separable residue field extensions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19408/discussion-between-miketex-and-david-lampert).

Comment: http://planetmath.org/separabilityisrequiredforintegralclosurestobefinitelygenerated : example of purely inseparable finite discrete valuation field extension (same completion) with non-finitely generated DVR extension and e=f=g=1.  I move on now.